# How to display custom pagination data in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, api, controller, resources

I am a laravel beginner and I would like to display custom data on the website because I am creating a REST-API. I wish it were something like this

```
success:   true
posts:
    1:
       post_id: 436523
       title: "Post Title"
       message: "Post Message"
       author: "Post Author"
meta:  [...]
```

and that it would be possible to customize meta / links and choose whether they should all be displayed or, for example, the meta itself without links

**My Code:**

```
class NewsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $posts = News::all();
        $i = 1;
        $data = [];
        foreach($posts as $post){
            $data[$i] = [
                'post_id'=> $post['post_id'],
                'icon'=> $post['icon'],
                'date'=> $post['created_on'],
                'title'=> $post['title'],
                'message'=> $post['message'],           
                'author'=> $post['author'],
            ];
            $i++;
        }
        
        $filter = new NewsFilter();
        $filterItems = $filter->transform($request);
        $news = News::where($filterItems);
        if(count($filterItems) == 0){
            return ['success'=> true, 'Posts Count'=> News::count(), 'posts'=> $data];
        }else{
            $news = new NewsCollection($news->paginate()->appends($request->query()));
            return ['success'=> true, $news];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to remove the contents of the `links` and `meta` arrays unless you overwrite the core functions that generate them.

Anyway, when it comes to adding data, you can use the [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources#top-level-meta-data) function to append any extra information.

Comment: I know it, but how do I use this notation ['success' => true, new NewsCollection($news->paginate()->appends($request->query()))]; it returns to me without links and meta and paginate normally returns with these data and I don't know why they disappear if I want to add something to it

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a way to accomplish what you're trying to do, but my opinion here would be to just stick to Laravel's schema. They've been improving their framework for years, and the current response is a standard that needs to be followed, IMHO. You don't really need a `success => true`: you can use the Response Status Code; You also have the necessary tools to add the extra information in the meta and links arrays.